# How can I add a button with onclick event to a list item that already has an onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list item that already has an onclick event:

```
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = list.title;
        li.addEventListener("click", async function(e) {
            window.location.replace("http://localhost:3000/list.html?title=" + e.target.textContent);
        })
```

Now I added a button to the list item:

```
        const trash = document.createElement("button");
        trash.style.float = "right";
        trash.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            alert("test")
        })
        li.appendChild(trash);
```

The Problem is that when I click on the button it fires the onclick event of my button, but afterwards the onclick event of the list item is fired aswell. I want my programm to only process one of the events depending on the element I clicked at.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: `click` events bubble.  You can `e.stopPropagation()` in the trash click event handler to stop this behavior.

Comment: Also side note; you don't need `async` on the event handler for the li click.  Doesn't really make sense.